# average of 2 classification reports

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

is there a way to take the average of two classification report?

so if I have this two reports

```
              precision-recall  f1-score   support

 downstairs    0.82      0.84      0.83       146
 jogging       0.99      1.00      1.00       146
 sitting       0.97      0.93      0.95       149
 standing      0.91      0.89      0.90       148
 upstairs      0.80      0.86      0.83       146
 walking       0.90      0.87      0.88       148

accuracy                            0.90      883
macro avg       0.90      0.90      0.90      883
weighted avg    0.90      0.90      0.90      883
```

AND

```
           precision-recall  f1-score   support

 downstairs    0.75      0.70      0.72       292
 jogging       0.99      0.97      0.98       291
 sitting       0.92      0.94      0.93       299
 standing      0.93      0.76      0.84       296
 upstairs      0.68      0.77      0.72       293
 walking       0.77      0.87      0.82       295

accuracy                           0.84      1766
macro avg       0.84      0.84     0.84      1766
weighted avg    0.84      0.84     0.84      1766
```

how to take the average values?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, could you explain in what situation you would need to do that?

Comment: @valentin calomme I am performing leave one out subject. That means every time different subjects are in the train and test set. So I end up with 6 classification reports but I need one that shows the average of the six

Comment: @redplanet I assume you mean cross-validation in general, rather than leave-one-out specifically, since your metrics should all be 0 or 1 if you only have 1 sample to test. Are you stratifying your folds? If the folds have different proportions of classes, a simple mean of sensitivity/specificity/precision/etc. over the folds won't give you the right answer, you'll need to do some class weighting, or store all the predictions and run your metrics once at the end.

Comment: hi @nuclear wang. Thanks you for your answer. No i mean leave on out subject. Take a look at the following code. 6 daasets from six people. Each time different of them in the train and test split

df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
for i in range(6):
    train = pd.concat(df_list[0:i] + df_list[i+1:])
    test = df_list[i]

Comment: @redplanet Are you saying you only have 6 data points? Or do you have a series of data points for each person that you're trying to predict?

Comment: each person is performing six activities for 10 minutes. for each activity, i have 30000 rows. so for each person, I have one dataset which has 7 columns (activity, accx, acct, accz, gyrx,gyry,gyrz) and nearly 180000 rows